# How to use a ProgressBar?

Tags: android, android-progressbar

I have a search function (using a web service) which takes a while to load data to my inflated layout. I want to show a `ProgressBar` untill the data is fetched from the web service. This is a small time interval and hence I don't to use a `ProgressDialog` for this. I've gone through many posts and *dev* guide but I'm not able to figure out a way to use that in my app. I've a `Spinner` in my layout. Once I choose an item from the spinner drop down I pass the string to the search function which fetches as well as loads data into the inflated layout.

```
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
            long arg3) {
        Selection = spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();           

        search(Selection);
    }
```

I created a ProgressBar, handler as explained in the *dev* guide.

```
private ProgressBar mProgress =  new ProgressBar(SearchActivity.this, null, android.R.attr.progressBarStyleSmall);
private int mProgressStatus = 0;

private Handler mHandler = new Handler();
```

And say this is a new thread used to display the `ProgressBar`

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
             while (mProgressStatus < 100) {
                 mProgressStatus = doWork();

                 // Update the progress bar
                 mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                     public void run() {
                         mProgress.setProgress(mProgressStatus);
                     }
                 });
             }
         }
     }).start();
```

How do I track progress of my search function to show the `ProgressBar`?

Thank you for reading

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an [`AsyncTask`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) instead of a thread. It's way easier to use and provides a built-in mechanism to be notified of progress updates.

Look at this question for a complete sample :

[Download a file with Android, and showing the progress in a ProgressDialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3028306/download-a-file-with-android-and-showing-the-progress-in-a-progressdialog)

Comment: I don't mind using AsyncTask but I don't want to a ProgresDialog. Can we show a ProgressBar using AsyncTask?

Comment: This code give the general idea, it's not hard to change it to update a `ProgressBar` instead. For example in `onPreExecute()` you can set the ProgressBar to 0%, then on each call to `onProgressUpdate()` you change its value to the specified amount.

Comment: All the tutorials have used `ProgressDialogs` I don't see any with `ProgressBars`. As far as I've learned `ProgressBar` requires progress to be tracked. You can't show a `ProgressBar` simply by using `.show()` like we use in `ProgressDialog` right?

Comment: No, just define it in your layout and you're done. You don't have to show/hide it like a `ProgressDialog`.

Answer (score 2):

You should use a [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) instead of a thread. A asyncTask let you to have a `preexecute`, `postexecute` and `publishprogress` which run on UI thread, and a `doInBackground` which run in background. There is a lot of tuts on [google](https://www.google.fr/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ie=UTF-8#hl=fr&safe=off&output=search&sclient=psy-ab&q=tuto%20async%20task%20progress%20bar%20download&oq=&gs_l=&pbx=1&fp=ce3444e3f77efdd7&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.,cf.osb&biw=1276&bih=683).

Try this [one](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/04/android-downloading-file-by-showing-progress-bar/).

Comment: I don't mind using `AsyncTask` but I don't want to a `ProgresDialog`. Can we show a `ProgressBar` using `AsyncTask`?

Comment: @Harsh Of course and it's easier with asynctasks. just look at the tut I linked in my answer

Comment: I didn't see any tutorials on how to show `ProgressBars` using `AsyncTask`. most of the headings say `ProgressBar` but they end up showing a `ProgressDialog`

Comment: @Harsh but it's the same! just use mProgressBar.setProgress(progress);

Comment: Okay. What's the value of progress that I am setting here? I'm sorry but I'm quite new to this.

Comment: @Harsh Follow the tut, and set the progress of your progressBar instead of the progress of the dialog